# unable to run java apache sparck maven project

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

When running the maven project i get the following error

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.2.0:java (default-cli) on project test_intelli: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x6f696f4) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x6f696f4
```

with the following pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argLine>--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                    <argLine>--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                    <argument>/home/user/Desktop/input.txt</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

java version:

openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13, mixed mode, sharing)

maven version:
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: N/A, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.7.8-zen1-1-zen", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

i ran mvn exec:java but unfortunately i ran into exceptions that weren't supposed to occur
it looks like it kind of works through i intellij project but i really need for it to work from command line and not from an ide

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

To address the error you're encountering, you need to ensure compatibility between your Java version (21.0.2) and the dependencies in your Maven project. This error likely stems from access restrictions introduced in newer Java versions. Check compatibility of your dependencies with Java 21.0.2, update Maven and relevant plugins, review Maven exec plugin configuration, and consider consulting project documentation or community for guidance. Additionally, verifying module declarations and trying different JDK versions might help resolve the issue.

Comment: hi, i switched to the latest version of spark and the error persists. i installed maven today through pacman so that isn't the issue